# Can I use the same binary on Linux, *BSD and Illumos?

Tags: linux, executable, bsd

I want to know, if I can use the binary of a program without modification on the three systems? After all they are all Unices. I talk about the same architecture.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, you cannot, as the [ABI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_binary_interface)s differ. Some BSDs do have binary compability with Linux binaries, with some caveats (enabling [virtual 8086 mode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_8086_mode) is a common issue). Often you may need to patch the source, however, as many binaries will make assumptions about their environment based on the fact that the source is developed for Linux. As far as I am aware there is no BSD-binary compatibility in the Linux kernel at this time.

Andrey Sokolov is [working on providing Linux binary support](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.os.openindiana.devel/294) on Illumos without zones, but as far as I am aware there is no BSD-binary compability on Illumos that is planned at this time.

Comment: Which ABI? As far as I know, most programs don't talk directly with the kernel, but with the libc (is that right?). Isn't it possible to provide a ABI-compatible libc?

Comment: The ABI depends on the platform the binary is being built for. [This article](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Compatibility.html) has some good information about binary compatibility which should help you.